# Do you need to make a Medicine check to use the second benefit of the Healer feat?

Tags: dnd-5e, feats, skills, healing

The [Healer](https://www.dndbeyond.com/feats/healer) feat (PHB, p. 167) says:

> When you use a healer’s kit to stabilize a dying creature, that creature also regains 1 hit point.
>
> As an action, you can spend one use of a healer’s kit to tend to a creature and restore 1d6 + 4 hit points to it, plus additional hit points equal to the creature’s maximum number of Hit Dice. The creature can’t regain hit points from this feat again until it finishes a short or long rest.

I know that a benefit from this feat is that you don't have to make a medicine check in order to stabilize a creature. However... For the second ability, is a Medicine check necessary in order to heal a creature?

I just got to use this feat for the first time yesterday and my DM had me roll a Medicine check. Is this accurate? Or does it depend on the DM?

Answer (score 8):

## No, you don't need to make a Medicine check

The [Healer's Kit](https://www.dndbeyond.com/equipment/healers-kit) states (emphasis mine):

> As an action, you can expend one use of the kit to stabilize a creature that has 0 hit points, **without needing to make a Wisdom (Medicine) check**.

The Healer feat says you can spend one use of the *healer's kit* to restore additional hitpoints, which is what makes the feat special. Otherwise you'd need to cast a spell, or use a potion, etc.

The rule of thumb is: if the Action requires a check, it will say so.